# Concatenate two file with a common pattern but with several lign

Tags: awk

I have two files :

File 1 (sep = tab):

```
A1 bla blo bli 23
A1 bla blo bli 21
A1 bla blo bli 28
B2 bla blo bli 32
B2 bla blo bli 31
B2 bla blo bli 35
```

File 2 (sep = ;):

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc
```

And I try to add the different value of each similar pattern of the File 1 to the File 2 like this :

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Do you have some awk command in order to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: why there are three `;` s following A2 and B1? is the `3` fixed value?

Comment: @Kent There are n fields per line with n-1 the maximum occurance in file1

Comment: @Kent no sorry it's not mandatory to have ";" in the lign that don't match with the other file

Comment: Please could you explain the problem more clearly, because it is totally unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}
     (NR==FNR){a[$1,++b[$1]] = $2; n=(n>b[$1]?n:b[$1]); next }
     { s=$1; for(i=1;i<=n;++i) s = s OFS a[$1,i]; print s }' FS="\t" file1 FS=";" file2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying two really understand the cmd in order to learn better awk syntax. I'm familiar with NR==FNR and how to process input from multiple file, but the specificity of this problem is tricky for me. 

It's seems that in your answer, you parse the first file as first column and then the rest, or if the file is not exactly as shown the code fail ; ie the first file can be like this : 
`A1  bla  blo  bli  23`

Same for the file 2 that is like this : 
`bla;blo,bli;A1;blu,bls`

Comment: I've just change my example to be more specific